# Debugging FFmpeg

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-ndk

I am using FFmpeg @ Android and would like to be able to step-in to the FFmpeg code ( Eclipse + Seqouya ), while compiling FFmpeg I use the `--disable-stripping --enable-debug=3` flags, still, stepping in with the debugger throws me at some unrelated line of code.

What settings should I use to enable FFmpeg debugging ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After some research, The only thing that was missing to enable stepping through ffmpeg code was adding ffmpeg build script `--extra-cflags="-gstabs+"`

Comment: This flag is now obsolete (2023)

Answer (score 5):

This works for me, not sure how much necessary/helpful:

```
--disable-optimizations --extra-cflags=-Og --extra-cflags=-fno-omit-frame-pointer --enable-debug=3 --extra-cflags=-fno-inline
```

Then use ffmpeg_g :)

Comment: damn! I kept running `ffmpeg` instead of `ffmpeg_g` and wondering why it wouldn't show symbols

Answer (score 1):

1 - Added an "--enable-debug" to the configure.
2 - Set the compiler debug option using the CFLAGS environment variable
using:

Export CFLAGS=" -g" Question: Can you pass "-g" as a make argument
instead?

3 - Run make